# How to split Full Name field into First Name, Last Name and Middle Initial?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with a  field called `PATRN NAME` which is set up with `First_Name, Last_Name M.I.`

Examples:

> Smith, James M
>
> Jones, Chris J.
>
> Anderson, Wendy L

How can I break up this field into 3 different fields called FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, and MI ? I tried running a query `LAST_NAME: [PATRN NAME]" & ", "` to get just the last name but it didn't get any results. I didn't design this table by the way so I realize it wasn't smart to make a full field name without individual field names; I'm just in charge of fixing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider whether you can bend the [Split Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-function-HA001228911.aspx) to your will.

Here is an example Immediate window session.

```vb
PATRN_NAME = "Smith, James M"
? PATRN_NAME
Smith, James M
? Split(PATRN_NAME, ",")(0)
Smith
? Trim(Split(PATRN_NAME, ",")(1))
James M
? Split(Trim(Split(PATRN_NAME, ",")(1)), " ")(0)
James
? Split(Trim(Split(PATRN_NAME, ",")(1)), " ")(1)
M
```

You can't use `Split()` in a query directly.  However you could build one or more user-defined functions and call the UDF(s) from a query.

That approach could make for a simpler query than one which requires a combination of other functions: `InStr()`, `Mid()`, `Right()`, etc.  However, a UDF means the query can only work from within an Access application session; if you need a query which runs from outside Access (.Net, VBScript, PHP, etc.), the UDF will not be available.

I suggest you clarify whether your intention is to extract `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, and `MI` every time you query the data, or whether you will store those values separately in the table after you extract them once.  That should influence the approach you choose.  If you will split them out once and store, you could use a VBA procedure instead of a query.

Also decide what should happen with the optional dot after the middle initial, *"Jones, Chris J."*.  Keep it in `MI` or discard it?

Comment: I just tried reading about the Split function but I don't quite understand it and therefore it's difficult for me to understand your code. Is this method easier than typing criteria into a query?

Comment: I only have to make the three new fields this one time. After I have the fields FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, and MI, then new data will be entered into those fields. I asked about using queries because I thought I could use a make table query to make these 3 new fields in a new table.

Comment: I also would like to remove the dot from the middle initial.

Comment: Then does this sound satisfactory? ---  A VBA procedure which reads each `[PATRN NAME]`, splits out the parts, discards dots, and stores the parts in `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, and `MI` fields.  (Would those fields be in the same table or a different table?)

Comment: That sounds fantastic and is exactly what I was trying to say. It would be better if they stayed in the same table but if it's easier to make a different table then that is completely fine.

Comment: Yeah, add those fields to your existing table's structure.  BTW, does the data have any first names which include spaces, such as "Jim Bob"?

Comment: I just looked and it does have some like that. This database is a disaster.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35015/discussion-between-hansup-and-database-intern)

Comment: I posted a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111169/how-to-split-a-name-field-that-has-incorrect-data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For last name:  `LAST_NAME: Mid(PATRN_NAME,1,InStr(PATRN_NAME,',')-1)`

For first name:  `FIRST_NAME: Mid(PATRN_NAME,InStr(PATRN_NAME,',')+2)`

For MI: `MI: Mid(Mid(PATRN_NAME,InStr(PATRN_NAME,',')+2),InStr(Mid(PATRN_NAME,InStr(PATRN_NAME,',')+2),' '),3)`

Comment: I tried all 3 of these but I got the error "Invalid dot or ! operator or invalid parentheses." I tried moving some parentheses around but I was unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Tbl_Master_Working SET Tbl_Master_Working.[Last Name] = Mid([NAME],1,InStr([NAME],',')-1), Tbl_Master_Working.[First Name] = Mid([NAME],InStr([NAME],',')+2);
```