# Macro for saving emails from outlook - Get the sender's last name

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get an Outlook macro to work that simply saves emails as .msg files, with specific formatting, for archiving reasons.

Analogous to another user on here, I am using the following piece of code, resulting in the file format "yymmdd_sender_title.msg", which is exactly what I want, except that I need to get the sender's **last name** only, instead of the whole name.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objItem As Object
Dim sPath As String
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim sName As String
Dim enviro As String
Dim sSenderName As String

enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
Set oMail = objItem

sName = oMail.subject
ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, ""


sSenderName = oMail.SenderName
dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
sName = Format(dtDate, "yymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
vbUseSystem) & "_" & sSenderName & "_" & sName & ".msg"

sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
Debug.Print sPath & sName
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

End If
Next

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
sChr As String _
)
sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only retrieve address entry details if it comes from the same Exchange server you are on `(AddressEntry.GetExchnageUserUser()`). Otherwise the display name is all that you get.

Comment: I don't really understand your reply. I am completely new to this stuff, the situation is as follows: People in my office save loads and loads of mails as .msg files and then format them *by hand*. I tried the script on lots of mails, it seems to work just fine, except that I want it to exlcude the sender's first name.

Comment: So do they come from other Exchange mailboxes? Try objItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.LastName. Be prepared to handle errors / nulls returned by objItem.Sender and objItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Split Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-Function-876f246a-5144-44fa-889f-10078c7878f5?CorrelationId=1205381d-1df3-4867-9473-6f2494c443b4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Example

```
    sSenderName = oMail.SenderName

    sSenderName = Split(sSenderName, " ")(1)
```

Then the rest of your code

[How to split Full Name field into First Name, Last Name and Middle Initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107309/how-to-split-full-name-field-into-first-name-last-name-and-middle-initial)

[Extracting First And Last Names](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FirstLast.htm)

Comment: Here is great example from @HansUp [How to split Full Name field into First Name, Last Name and Middle Initial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107309/how-to-split-full-name-field-into-first-name-last-name-and-middle-initial)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I came to realize that there might be a more fundamental problem:

People's names in my inbox are written "as is", depending on how they set up their mail account, i.e. sometimes last names come first, sometimes they dont (Mike Johnson vs. Johnson, Mike) - among other, more rare formattings.

I got a workaround so that for these two usual cases, there's now 2 different scripts to run, i.e. you have to choose by hand which mails are formatted last/first name and which ones are first/last name. I guess this is as good as it gets :)